# disabled MS Entra ADO user is showing recently accessed ADO

Tags: azure-devops

We disabled a user(s) in MS Entra several months/years ago, but in ADO org settings, it is showing those users recently accessed ADO few days ago. How is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that disabled users cannot log in anymore, it indicates that the account has been blocked when trying to access the Azure DevOps organization. And the "`Last Accessed`" date will not be updated in ADO org settings.

[image]

Based on your screenshot, it appears that the affected account was recently enabled again or never been disabled successfully. Another possible is that you have two users in your Entra ID with the same display name, the disabled one is not exactly the affected one shown in your screenshot.

Anyway, please check the user settings in your Entra ID to ensure that the exact user is really disabled, also check the user settings log to see if another administrator enabled the account and disabled it again during the affected time period.

BTW, for users who don't intend to use it long-term, it is recommended that you directly delete it from the organization and add it again when needed.

Comment: those Users are in disabled state only. tying to find if we are missing anything while we are cleaning up ADO orgs. Ty for the reply.

Comment: @Bavanari Yeah, please check it. You can also try using another disabled test user, just try logging into Azure DevOps and see if you can see the lock message mentioned in the screenshot above. To check whether the disabled state has taken effect.